# Save file inside an operator

Tags: python

I have written a simple operator to save the current blender file, but when the operator reaches the save function I get an error. I used the `bpy.ops.save_as_mainfile()` function for saving a scene, but I don't know if it's the right one to choose.

The console outputs this error:

```
TypeError: 'BPyOpsSubMod' object is not callable
location: /opt/blender/2.70/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:188
```

Does that mean I cannot call functions from `bpy.ops`?

My script is the the following:

```
import bpy
class SaveOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.save_op"
    bl_label = "Save scene"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):

        # build file name stuff
        # ...

        bpy.ops.save_as_mainfile('~/' + new_file_name)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SaveOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SaveOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.save_op()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass your parameters as keyword arguments. See [api docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.html#keywords-and-positional-arguments)

The correct call should be `bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=your_path)`

Comment: Yeah, this might be the correct answer. But this ends up in the following error: Cannot open file ~/untitled0012.blend@ for writing: No such file or directory. I don't know why there is a @ symbol in the error message, but the filepath is without it. Maybe blender has a problem with creating a file. I also tried it with open() command and it ended in a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Try using an absolute path. Have a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)