# How to save an animation using python

Tags: python

I have written a python code to build a simple animation. I need to save this animation (.blend) in a specific path. I used `Save(path)` in Blender 2.49b but I don't know how to use in Blender 2.74.
Any tips?

Comment: related, and same answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/save-file-inside-an-operator?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, you can even name the file during the save:

```
fp = "/home/username/SomeFolder/doubles.blend"  # or whatever you use.
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=fp)
```